# Routing to page A or Page B based on API response

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I am stuck on an issue. Let's say I have a home page. From this home page, I want to route to either page A or page B.

I have a list of items on the home page and what I need to do is when I click on any item in the list, it makes a GET API call, and based on one field in the response which is a boolean, I either need to redirect to page A or page B.

Basically, I need to call an API on the click of the item and get the response before it is routed to either Page A or Page B.

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

if you're using Next.JS, use [useRouter](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router) prop to achieve this.

for example

```
import {useRouter} from "next/router";

export default function Page() {
    const router = useRouter()

    async function route() {
        let res = await apiFunctionCall();
        if (res) {
            await router.replace({
                pathname: '/page1'
            })
        } else {
            await router.replace({
                pathname: 'page2'
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The closest solution I could get is to create a Lazy loaded component which calls the API and then based on the response, routes to either page A or Page B.

Before routing to the correct page based on the data that has been returned, the data first needs to be stored in a variable. The data will be stored in the `res` variable. The `if else` statement will then route to either page A or B based on the data.

```
<code>const Response = res.data;

if(Response.type === 'A'){
  this.props.history.push('/page-a');
} else {
  this.props.history.push('/page-b');
}
</code>
```